# ClassNotFoundException when running `mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs`

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I'm at the following step of a GCP [openapi guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-endpoints-appengine/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3) where I have to run a maven command to generate an `openapi.json` file.

I'm following along with my own project, so this may or not be reproducible by just forking the [example repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-backend). (so I wouldn't, because I link my own below)

[image]

So when I run the command they tell me to, I get the following stack trace, complaining that they can't find my api class, when it very clearly exists.

```sh
C:\Users\********\Projects\********>mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< xyz.********:rest >-------------------------
[INFO] Building rest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:2.0.1:openApiDocs (default-cli) @ rest ---
[INFO] Endpoints Tool params : [get-openapi-doc, -o, C:\Users\********\Projects\********\target\openapi-docs\openapi.json, -cp, C:\Users\********\Projects\********\target\classes;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.3.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.3.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.3.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.3.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.13.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.2.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.13.2\log4j-api-2.13.2.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.30\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.26\snakeyaml-1.26.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore\1.2.3.RELEASE\spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-gcp-starter\1.2.3.RELEASE\spring-cloud-gcp-starter-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-gcp-core\1.2.3.RELEASE\spring-cloud-gcp-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-core\1.93.4\google-cloud-core-1.93.4.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-iam-v1\0.13.0\proto-google-iam-v1-0.13.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\auth\google-auth-library-oauth2-http\0.20.0\google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure\1.2.3.RELEASE\spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore\1.2.3.RELEASE\spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\reactor-core\3.3.5.RELEASE\reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.3\reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-firestore\1.33.0\google-cloud-firestore-1.33.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\google-cloud-core-grpc\1.93.4\google-cloud-core-grpc-1.93.4.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-core\1.28.1\grpc-core-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\android\annotations\4.1.1.4\annotations-4.1.1.4.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\perfmark\perfmark-api\0.19.0\perfmark-api-0.19.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-cloud-firestore-admin-v1\1.33.0\proto-google-cloud-firestore-admin-v1-1.33.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1\1.33.0\proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1-1.33.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1beta1\0.86.0\proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1beta1-0.86.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\value\auto-value-annotations\1.7\auto-value-annotations-1.7.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-contrib-grpc-util\0.24.0\opencensus-contrib-grpc-util-0.24.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api\api-common\1.9.0\api-common-1.9.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-protobuf\1.28.1\grpc-protobuf-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-protobuf-lite\1.28.1\grpc-protobuf-lite-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-context\1.28.1\grpc-context-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.11.4\protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-common-protos\1.17.0\proto-google-common-protos-1.17.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api\gax\1.56.0\gax-1.56.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-api\1.28.1\grpc-api-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.3.4\error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.18\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.18.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api\gax-grpc\1.56.0\gax-grpc-1.56.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-auth\1.28.1\grpc-auth-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-netty-shaded\1.28.1\grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-alts\1.28.1\grpc-alts-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-grpclb\1.28.1\grpc-grpclb-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\conscrypt\conscrypt-openjdk-uber\2.2.1\conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\threeten\threetenbp\1.4.3\threetenbp-1.4.3.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-stub\1.28.1\grpc-stub-1.28.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\opencensus\opencensus-api\0.24.0\opencensus-api-0.24.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\auth\google-auth-library-credentials\0.20.0\google-auth-library-credentials-0.20.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.6\gson-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java-util\3.11.4\protobuf-java-util-3.11.4.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\grpc-google-cloud-firestore-v1\1.33.0\grpc-google-cloud-firestore-v1-1.33.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.3.0.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\endpoints\endpoints-framework\2.2.1\endpoints-framework-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\20.0\guava-20.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.11.0\jackson-annotations-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.11.0\jackson-core-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.11.0\jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\flogger\flogger\0.3.1\flogger-0.3.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-jackson2\1.25.0\google-http-client-jackson2-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client\1.25.0\google-http-client-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.12\httpclient-4.5.12.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.13\httpcore-4.4.13.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.14\commons-codec-1.14.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api-client\google-api-client\1.25.0\google-api-client-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client\1.25.0\google-oauth-client-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api-client\google-api-client-appengine\1.25.0\google-api-client-appengine-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client-appengine\1.25.0\google-oauth-client-appengine-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\oauth-client\google-oauth-client-servlet\1.25.0\google-oauth-client-servlet-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-jdo\1.25.0\google-http-client-jdo-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\api-client\google-api-client-servlet\1.25.0\google-api-client-servlet-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\javax\jdo\jdo2-api\2.3-eb\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\transaction-api\1.1\transaction-api-1.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\http-client\google-http-client-appengine\1.25.0\google-http-client-appengine-1.25.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.1\jsr305-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.3.3\commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.2\commons-io-2.2.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-models\1.5.9\swagger-models-1.5.9.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.5.9\swagger-annotations-1.5.9.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-core\1.5.9\swagger-core-1.5.9.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.10\commons-lang3-3.10.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-joda\2.11.0\jackson-datatype-joda-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.9\joda-time-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-yaml\2.11.0\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-nop\1.7.30\slf4j-nop-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\endpoints\endpoints-management-control-appengine-all\1.0.12\endpoints-management-control-appengine-all-1.0.12.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.80\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.80.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\********\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.12\lombok-1.18.12.jar;C:\Users\********\Projects\********\target\classes, -w, C:\Users\********\Projects\********\src\main\webapp, -h, course-gen.appspot.com]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.725 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-08T15:59:58-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:2.0.1:openApiDocs (default-cli) on project rest: Endpoints Tool Error: xyz.********.rest.CourseApi -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:2.0.1:openApiDocs (default-cli) on project rest: Endpoints Tool Error
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Endpoints Tool Error
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.endpoints.framework.OpenApiDocsMojo.execute (OpenApiDocsMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xyz.*********.rest.api.CourseApi
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetOpenApiDocAction.loadClasses (GetOpenApiDocAction.java:139)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetOpenApiDocAction.genOpenApiDoc (GetOpenApiDocAction.java:111)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetOpenApiDocAction.execute (GetOpenApiDocAction.java:82)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.execute (EndpointsTool.java:84)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.endpoints.framework.OpenApiDocsMojo.execute (OpenApiDocsMojo.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

IntelliJ recognizes it as path and refactors it automatically whenever I move it around. The path in question is defined in the `web.xml`. (servlet -> init-param -> param-value)

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <!-- Wrap the backend with Endpoints Frameworks v2. -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>xyz.********.rest.api.CourseApi</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Route API method requests to the backend. -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- [START api_management] -->
    <!-- Add a filter that fetches the service config from service management. -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Add a filter that performs Endpoints logging and monitoring. -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
            <param-value>${endpoints.project.id}</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
            <param-value>${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- [END api_management] -->
</web-app>
```

Edit: figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was so simple - `mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs` only sees the last version of your repository built by `mvn package` (which I assume is in target or something).

So I had updated my code but never reran `mvn package` so that's why the class could not be found.